# Identifying the key id of a service account in Stackdriver logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-iam

I have a GCP project. I have created a service account with two JSON keys (key ids). For brevity's sake, let's call them `Key A` and `Key B`.

When the keys are created, I can see in the JSON file that each one has a unique `private_key_id` property. Both keys share the same `client_email` obviously e.g. `foo@project-id-here.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

In Stackdriver logging, I can see the `client_email` of service account being used. However, the audit logs don't differentiate between the keys attached to the actual service account. In other words, all I see in the logs is (this example shows access to BigQuery):

```
  ..authenticationInfo: {
   principalEmail:  "foo@project-id-here.iam.gserviceaccount.com"    
  }
  authorizationInfo: [
   0: {
    granted:  true     
    permission:  "bigquery.jobs.create"     
    resource:  "projects/project-id-here"     
   }
   1: {
    granted:  true     
    permission:  "bigquery.jobs.create"     
    resource:  "projects/project-id-here"     
   }
  ]..
```

**How can I see which key for the service account was actually used i.e. `Key A` or `Key B`?**

Comment: That is a good question. I have never seen the private key ID logged by Stackdriver. I think this will make a good feature request because of auditing key usage.

Comment: This also brings up the question when a service account is used by a service, a key has not actually been generated for the service that we can see. What should be logged in this case for the private key ID?

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable request but this isn't currently (generally) possible.

I recommend you file a FR on Google's Issue Track for Logging:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187203&template=1162662